# File/pipe writing of a simple interface program

Tags: pipe, gnuplot

I recently created a simple program that iterates through a numerical calculation, writes the results to 3 files, and then passes these files to Gnuplot. As a command line tool everything seemed to work, but I have moved all the same code into a program with a simple interface on Xcode and I'm not getting any graphs output. I stepped through the program in the debugger and everything seems to be working (the pipe to gnuplot, files, all the objects all seem to have been created and everything happens in the order its supposed to), but there's no visible output. Should the following code still work?

```
FILE *SomeFile=fopen("SomeFile.txt", "w");
fprintf(SomeFile, "%g\t", SomeNumber);
FILE *pipe=popen("gnuplot", "w");

fprintf(pipe, "plot \"%s\"\n", [filename UTF8String])
```

where the file name in the NSString filename is SomeFile.txt .

This worked fine in the command line program, any idea where I'm going wrong now?

Comment: What happens if you add `fprintf(pipe,"set term post;set output 'foo.ps'\n");`?  Do you get a plot `foo.ps`?  Another thing to look into is flushing SomeFile (`fflush(SomeFile);`).  If your output is buffered, then it's possible that there is no data in the file at the time gnuplot tries to read it.

Comment: You were 100% right about flushing the files/pipe, thank you! Appreciate the help - I would upvote you if I could :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you flush the datafile before you tell gnuplot to read it, otherwise, gnuplot might see an empty datafile:

```
fprintf(SomeFile, "%g\t", SomeNumber);
fflush(SomeFile);
```